# Geotarget global audience with .com.au

Tags: seo, top-level-domains, geotargeting

We were trying to buy our `.com.au` in `.com` form but it's taken already.

Is there a way to set a `.com.au` to have a global geotarget?

Does a `.com` have any geotargetting associated with it? If so is there a way to mimic these settings with the `.com.au` domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google does not allow many country top level domains (ccTLDs) to be geo-targetted globally](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2286477/Matt-Cutts-Be-Careful-About-How-You-Choose-Your-ccTLDs).  This includes `com.au`.  There is no way to get a `com.au` domain to show up in global Google search, only in Google searches from Australia.

If you want a generic TLD that can be targeted globally in Google search, you must choose one from [this list published by Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1347922?hl=en).